# Vue custom element as web component and vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, web-component, custom-element

I have a vue 3 app which builds some web components as custom elements. That works fine, I can define an html tag and use it in other apps and in my own vue app. I export the styles with the `.ce.vue` file ending.

Now I want to use the web components as normal vue components inside my app, but then the styles are not applied anymore. When I remove the custom element tag (the `ce.vue.` file ending), the vue component looks fine, but the web component loses it's styling.

Is there a way to be able to use a component in both ways, as a vue component and a web component?